# MegaRAID Storage Manager constantly beeping

Tags: megaraid, megaraid-storage-manager

I have a home-built Supermicro file server in my office with a very beepy RAID controller. It's about 4 years old, and for the first 2 years everything was fine. Around then a drive failed, which I replaced, nothing unusual. However since then, every time the machine is rebooted, the RAID alarm goes off, and the only way to silence it is to click 'silence alarm' within MegaRAID Storage Manager. Since it's a Windows Server, this happens quite a lot.
I have updated all firmware/software to the latest I can find, that's MRSM 17.05.00.02, Avago 3108 card firmware 4.650.00-6223. 
The status of the controller is 'Optimal' in both MRSM and the Supermicro IPMI, and there are no visible warning in any of the logs. I even tried disabling the alarm in the RAID BIOS when booting, but it still beeps.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the "Copy Back" feature is turned on. Basically a drive that was replaced has to be in the same slot because if not, it will keep beeping. Rather annoying functionality imho so I disable "Copy Back" on my servers like this:
https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161502838/megaraid-controller-still-beeps-after-rebuild-completes-and-vd-i

Comment: Thank-you for the answer, it still happens to this day no matter if all RAIDs are 'optimal'. I'll take a look at that setting. If I've understood that article correctly, it seems that Copy Back doesn't actually need to be on, it's just something that's nice to have.

Comment: Only if you care about the same slots being filled. Say your RAID-5 array is in slots 1,2,3 with slot 4 being a hot spare. Now drive in slot 2 fails and the array is rebuilt using the hot spare from slot 4. Even after it's done rebuilding it will continue beeping because the original array was in slots 1,2,3 and it wants to copy back to those slots. It's kind of a silly feature IMHO.

Comment: Disabling "Copy Back" did indeed solve the beeping! Ahhh, the beautiful sound of silence... Thank-you very much for the advice